# show border grid lines only between elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to use the CSS `border` attribute to make a fine `1px` grid between `span` elements, like so.

```
     |    
  1  |  2  
-----|-----
  3  |  4  
     |
```

This is what I currently have. It doesn't quite work obviously.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div {
    width: 204px;
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the `div` is set to `306px` and the elements reflow, the solution should adapt dynamically.

```
     |     |
  1  |  2  |  3
-----|-----|-----
  4  |
     |
```

Preferably CSS only, or pure Javascript. Older browsers like IE7 can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this solution, which automatically sets the border.

http://jsfiddle.net/aLz2T/3/

HTML

```
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>​
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 204px; /* adjust to get less/more columns */
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
}​
```

JavaScript

```
var a = document.querySelector('div');

// columns
var b = parseInt(a.offsetWidth / (100 + 2), 10);

for(var c, d = document.querySelectorAll('span'), e = d.length, i = 0; c = d[i]; i++) {
    // column
    c.style.borderRightWidth = ((i + 1) % b) != 0 ? "1px" : "0";
    // row
    c.style.borderBottomWidth = parseInt(i / b, 10) * b < e - b ? "1px" : "0";
}​
```

Answer (score 23):

I came up with this approach, which I think works pretty well with minimal CSS and hacks: https://codepen.io/eriklharper/pen/JMKMqa

```css
    .border {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(auto, auto));
      grid-gap: 1px;
    }
    .grid > div {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="border">
      <div class="grid">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It introduces an extra wrapping element around the whole grid (which isn't perfect either) but I've found this to be a worthwhile compromise, despite.  The lack of ability to simply style the `grid-gap`s directly is a shortcoming with CSS Grid that should be addressed with the spec.

Comment: Your example contains selectors that are not actually CSS: `& > div`. It would be nice to mention that so you don't confuse newbies. (Or just re-write it in pure CSS.)

Comment: Why not use `background-color: gray;` on the grid container itself? You wouldn't need an extra wrapping element or am I wrong?

Comment: if you also want a border around the entire grid, use `. grid {border: 1px solid gray;}`

Answer (score 4):

### 1. *HTML+CSS* solution

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <i></i>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <i></i>
</div>​
```

*CSS:*

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 202px;  /* or 303px (or 100px * n + n) */
    font-size: 0;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

i {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

​i:first-child {
    height: auto;
    width: 1px;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HTgKJ/

---

### 2. *HTML+CSS+JavaScript* solution

*HTML+CSS:*

```
<!-- See approach 1. -->
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var block = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    var spanWidth = block[i].querySelector("span").clientWidth,
        n = Math.floor(block[i].clientWidth / spanWidth);
    
    block[i].querySelector("i:first-child").style.left =
        (n * spanWidth + (n - 1)) + "px";
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HTgKJ/1/

Comment: This works, but rather than covering the lines up, I've rather not have them in the first place. The former can cause some alignment problems when zooming. I'm using a different solution, which is a bit like the other answer, but in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the background color of the containing element the color you want for the border.
2. Make the background color of the elements within the grid the color you really want as the background.
3. Add a gap of 1, or the desired border thickness.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  background-color: orange;
  gap : 1;  
}

.grid > * {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[image: how it looks]