# CSS grid gap color while using repeat

Tags: css, background, css-grid

In this example I'm creating grid cells *using just a repeat option*:

```
<div class="test"></div>
.test {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10px 10px 10px repeat(3, 10px);
    grid-template-columns: 15px repeat( 3, 10px );
    background-color: lime;
    gap: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anniebbird/s73enpyd/6/

Here is the grid when I inspect it with developer tools:

[image]

I wonder is it possible to make those gaps visible with a different color? Basically, I need to show borders between the cells.

*Clarification: as I showed in my example my grid will **not** have child elements, but a variable (and dynamic) number of cells built using the repeat option, that's why it's tricky*

Comment: I think you might have to have individual child elements for each grid square, and use `background-color` on `.test` for the colour of the grid gaps, and set `background-color` of each child to something different.

Comment: Just give the grid container a background color to the children

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Grid: Is it possible to apply color to grid gaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884630/css-grid-is-it-possible-to-apply-color-to-grid-gaps)

Comment: this will not work because my grid will not have child elements, but a variable number of cells built using the repeat option as I showed in my example

Comment: You can try removing gap and giving borders to grid blocks and give color to borders?

Comment: there are no grid blocks, they were created with repeat option